# Galaxy Nexus execute AT commands?

Tags: android, modem, at-command, galaxy-nexus

Would it be possible to send AT commands to the Galaxy Nexus using Hyperterminal or an other program?
If so, is there also a way to directly execute the commands on the phone?

Comment: No one tried to do this with a Nexus?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible on Linux (haven't tried on Win), but you'll need root on your GNex:

1. Connect rooted GNex to Linux PC with USB cable (debug mode and superuser access over adb must be enabled)
2. Go into adb shell and change to root with su command:

   adb shell

   su
3. as root execute the following:

   echo MODEM > /sys/devices/tuna_otg/usb_sel

This would drop you out of the adb shell and you should now have 7 new pseudo-tty devices in /dev named ttyACM[0-6]. You should now be able to use /dev/ttyACM0 to send AT commands to you GNex.

Personally, I use [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) to send the AT commands.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't send AT commands to the Galaxy Nexus, but it is possible with other mobile phones.  They act like Plug and Pr/lay devices when you connect them to a Windows computer.

Plug the phone in, then check Windows Device Manager to see if there's a modem port for the phone.

If you can see the phone as a modem, then that's the port to which you can send AT commands via Hyperterminal.

I'm not aware of any phones that let you enter AT commands into the phone via its keypad (that's what you mean, isn't it?).  The interface just isn't there.

If the phone shows up on the computer as a Windows Mobile Broadband device, you could also use Mobile Broadband API - documentation [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  You would have to write some code for that.
It depends on the driver support whether this is possible or not.